# How can I send Arduino sensors data to java application?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, java

my final year project is to do an Arduino watch that has heart rate and body temperature sensors and also a location tracking module. I need to send all the watch data to my java app but I don't how do I need to send it to a database first and then use it? and how can i do that.
I'm using arduino uno and i want to send the data to a database on a server.

I'm using android studio and coding with java

please help :(

Comment: To what database do you want to send the data? Where does the database run? How is the Arduino Uno connected to the system running the database?

Comment: I asked my teacher and she told me I have to read the data and send it to the server and the server will store it in a database and then display it in the application

Comment: i don't know how to work with Arduino it is my first time and i just want to know how i will receive the data to display it in the app

Comment: Then you first need to think about how to contact your server, so you need a network connection. Do you need to use an Arduino Uno? Do you have a wifi network available? Or do you need a mobile data connection over LTE? Have you done research about these things?

Answer (score 1):

To send the data from the Arduino, you just need to do this:

```cpp
Serial.println(the_data);
```

But then you have to manage some communication link between the Arduino
and whatever is going to collect the data. Typical choices are the USB
link or a Bluetooth module. Then, whatever you do with this data (send
to an Android phone, a Java app, a server, a database, whatever...) is
up to you, and is *not an Arduino question*.